# Manipulating the iphone triple-homebutton-click programmatically in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, home-button

So basically I'm wondering if it would be possible to programmatically manipulate the triple-click function on the iPhone. Basically, whenever you triple-click the home button you can choose in the settings between a few set actions to occur, like inverting colours, enabling zoom etc. I'm wondering if it's possible to programmatically implement *any* action to occur whenever the user triple-clicks on the home button.

Comment: Not on the app store. It's probably possible when jailbroken, but not on stock iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple does not allow direct access to the home or lock buttons on the device plain and simple.

Comment: This is not entirely true, you can modify the behavior of the volume buttons.

Comment: My mistake. Fixed my answer.